# Alloy: different instances for integer

Tags: alloy

I'm new to alloy and i'm doing a little project. In the project i have some instances with different attributes that, with magic layout, i can put in the instance when showing the model. Is there a way to do the same thing with integers?  I attach an image that i hope can describe better my issue, in the image you can see that the attributes occupied and type are in the socket, but the socketID no. So, i also wanted to put the integers (for example) in the socket to have a show without some useless instances/relations. I tried with the same approach used for the other attributes but is not working. I think it's because is an integer and not a custom sig.
I hope that the question is clear and thanks a lot in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure it's due to Magical Layout, unless they have implemented a special treatment for ints.

Anyway, the solution is to customize the "theme" yourself:
open the theme customization panel (e.g. by clicking the Theme icon).

Now two trees are displayed on the left, representing (top) the signature hierarchy and (bottom) all relations in your model: click there on `socketId` and then, at the top of the left panel, tick "Show as attribute" and untick "Show as arc", then apply your new theme by clicking Apply (top right), then click Close to close theme customization.